MethodError in Training Minimal U-Net
I need to implement a U-Net in Julia using Flux.jl. The ultimate goal is to train a neural network for a scientific problem. As a first step, I decided to experiment with the KITTI benchmark dataset.
Since I have more experience with Python, I initially implemented the U-Net in PyTorch, which worked perfectly. Then, I tried to translate my code into Julia while learning Flux.jl. Unfortunately, my implementation hasn't worked as expected.
To simplify the problem, I scaled back and attempted to implement a minimal U-Net model in Julia with synthetic data. However, I keep running into the following error during training:
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#17#19"{var"#loss#18"{…}, Array{…}, Array{…}})(::@NamedTuple{layers::Tuple{…}})

The function #17 exists, but no method is defined for this combination of argument types.

The numbers in #17 change depending on the code.
What I Have Done:

Created a minimal U-Net model with a few convolutional and transposed convolutional layers.

Used synthetic 64x64 input images and binary masks as the dataset.

Attempted to train the model with a basic training loop using Flux.jl's gradient function and the logitcrossentropy loss.

Experimenting with different U-Net implementations (e.g., this repo).


I suspect the issue might be with:

The shape of the model's output not matching the target shape.
The loss function not returning a scalar value, which is required for gradient computation.

Example
Here is the code that reproduces the issue:
I´m using Julia Version 1.11.1 and Flux v0.16.0
using Flux 
using Flux: Conv, ConvTranspose, relu, MaxPool, Dense, Chain, params
using Base.Iterators: partition
using Random
using Plots 

# Summary:
# This code defines a U-Net architecture for image segmentation using the Flux library in Julia.
# It creates synthetic data, prepares batches, trains the U-Net model, and tests the trained model.
# The problem is to ensure the U-Net model is correctly implemented and trained on the synthetic dataset.

# Define the U-Net architecture
function unet(input_channels::Int, output_channels::Int)
    encoder = Chain(
        Conv((3, 3), input_channels => 64, pad=1), relu, MaxPool((2, 2), stride=(2, 2)),
        Conv((3, 3), 64 => 128, pad=1), relu, MaxPool((2, 2), stride=(2, 2)),
        Conv((3, 3), 128 => 256, pad=1), relu, MaxPool((2, 2), stride=(2, 2)),
        Conv((3, 3), 256 => 512, pad=1), relu, MaxPool((2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
    )
    
    decoder = Chain(
        ConvTranspose((3, 3), 512 => 256, stride=2, pad=1), relu,
        ConvTranspose((3, 3), 256 => 128, stride=2, pad=1), relu,
        ConvTranspose((3, 3), 128 => 64, stride=2, pad=1), relu,
        ConvTranspose((3, 3), 64 => output_channels, stride=2, pad=1)
    )
    
    return Chain(encoder, decoder, x -> x[:, 1:64, 1:64, :])
end

# Create a synthetic dataset for image segmentation
function create_test_data(num_samples::Int)
    data = []
    for _ in 1:num_samples
        image = rand(Float32, 64, 64, 1)
        mask = rand(Bool, 64, 64, 1)
        push!(data, (image, mask))
    end
    return data
end

# Split the synthetic dataset into batches
function prepare_batches(data, batch_size::Int)
    batches = []
    for batch in partition(data, batch_size)
        input_batch = cat([x[1] for x in batch]..., dims=4)
        mask_batch = cat([x[2] for x in batch]..., dims=4)
        push!(batches, (input_batch, mask_batch))
    end
    return batches
end

# Implement a training loop for the U-Net model
function train_unet(model, train_data, num_epochs::Int, learning_rate::Float64)
    opt = ADAM(learning_rate)
    loss(x, y) = Flux.logitcrossentropy(model(x), float(y))
    
    for epoch in 1:num_epochs
        for (input_batch, mask_batch) in train_data
            gs = gradient(() -> loss(input_batch, mask_batch), Flux.trainable(model))
            Flux.Optimise.update!(opt, Flux.trainable(model), gs)
        end
        println("Epoch $epoch complete")
    end
end

# Test a trained U-Net model
function test_unet(model, test_image)
    prediction = model(test_image)
    plot(plot(test_image[:, :, 1, 1], title="Input Image"),
         plot(prediction[:, :, 1, 1], title="Predicted Mask"),
         layout=(1, 2))
end

# Example usage
model = unet(1, 1)
data = create_test_data(100)
batches = prepare_batches(data, 8)
train_unet(model, batches, 10, 0.001)
test_image, _ = data[1]
test_unet(model, test_image)

Why does the above code result in the said error, and how can I fix it?
I've tried ensuring that the shapes of the model's output and target match, but I suspect the issue lies in either the loss function or the gradient call.

Your error typically refers to a wrong call to the gradient function. However, I tried replacing gs = gradient(() -> loss(input_batch, mask_batch), Flux.trainable(model)) by grads = Flux.gradient(model) do m                 result = m(input_batch)                 loss(result, float(mask_batch))             end following https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/guide/training/training/, but it gave another error ERROR: LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 49×49×1×8 Array{Float32, 4} at index [1:49, 1:64, 1:64, 1:8]
